# Но лучших учеников(,) возможно)(,) не было среди них

Tags: пунктуация

Но лучших учеников возможно не было среди них.

Answer (score 2):

> “возможно” выделяется запятыми?

В приведённом Вами предложении является **вводным**, выделяется запятыми.

Подробнее о **"возможно"** см. [здесь.](http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/149)